# How could a facehugger attach to a Predator?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator-series

The predators have fangs on the exterior of their mouths. Shouldn't these provide some protection from the facehuggers? They show in all the movies they are in that they are capable of moving the fangs, you would think they would, in a desperate situation, use them to stop the facehuggers from latching on.

Clarification: I am asking specifically whether the fangs of the Predator could help defend against a facehugger. Not about the versatility of the facehuggers themselves.

Comment: The facehuggers melted through a clear helmet faceplate that's probably able to hold up to ballistic slugs. What do you think fangs would do?

Comment: The blood would kill the predator, but they seem to be of the opinion that death would be better than infection.

Comment: Who would win if a shark fought a gorilla?

Comment: It's not clear, but seems likely that the facehuggers don't kill their hosts unless they have no choice in the matter. They can be selective in using the acid.

Comment: @Mechatankzilla This isn't a shark vs gorilla type question, though. They share a universe (there have been at least two movies where both appear), and this isn't asking which of the two would win.

Comment: It really seems no different than trying to protect your face with just your pinky fingers.  Not very effective in my opinion.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist To me the question pretty much reads as Predator > Facehugger in a fight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The external fangs on a predator may be mostly for show. Perhaps at some point in their evolution they had a purpose, but for many generations they have not been functional. Although they can move them in threatening manners, it seems unlikely they can do so with a lot of power.

The way the external fangs (the fangs in the four corners of the predator's external mouth as it opens) are connected doesn't seem to allow for a lot of muscle. It appears, to me at least, to be more of a membrane that can close over something -- compare this to a human jaw, or the inner set of fangs on the predator. These are attached to large, solid bones which would allow for much more powerful muscles which are capable of biting with considerable strength.

I feel the fangs would not be useful -- predator anatomy (as I have seen it) does not seem to support them having a lot of strength (or, for that matter, fine motor control) of the outer fangs. While they might be able to cause them to protrude in an effort to combat the facehuggers, this seems highly unlikely to be able to fight them off.